# Can't install 'Screencast keys' add-on

Tags: add-on

User preferences, add-ons, won't recognize .py (screencast keys) file when I try to "install from file".  Oddly, it won't show up in Blender when the .py script is put into program files alongside all the all "view" files ending in .py.

Comment: It's an old addon, support was dropped a few versions ago. It probably hasn't been updated for a while so something might have broken in the meantime. Developers advised using some equivalent external program instead.

Comment: The addon support is indeed is dropped, however it works for me on 2.77. Try not installing addon rather than simply copying .py file to *<blender-dir-folder>/<blender-version>/scripts/addons*. If it still doesn't work then consider searching for alternative.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mod of the addon that works:

cd ~/.blender/*/scripts/addons/

git clone https://github.com/chromoly/blender-ScreencastKeysMod.git

then activate the addon

3D View > Properties Panel >Screencast Keys